# How to distribute a built executable constructed using electron-builder

Tags: node.js, electron, executable, electron-builder

I have recently packaged an electron app using electron-builder:

```
myProject/
├── package.json
├── app/
└── release/
```

All files created by electron-builder are place in the release directory. The executable works fine on my local machine, with all features present through the packaged app.

However, once I move the application to another machine only some features are available. Noticeably features within subdirectories in app/ are not included.

For example here a snippet of the app/ directory:

```
app/
├── app.html
├── index.js
├── components/
└── other files and folders
```

Features added from .js/.html files within components/ are not present when I move the app to another machine. I have tried both moving just the executable as well as the whole release/ directory, neither includes additional features beyond what is included in app.html.

**Update**

It does indeed look like any other machine simply doesn't read items contained in

```
<script></script>
```

In my app.html file

Would there be some outside installation I need to do on another machine to get this executable running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue,

It involved my usage of a two `package.json` structure

Both `dependencies` and `devDependencies` of my `build` were located in the `root/package.json`, where dependencies needed to be moved to the `app/package.json` file