# Why are multiple executables and setup files included as a result of my electron-builder?

Tags: node.js, electron, executable, electron-builder

I have been using Electron and Node to create and Electron based app and recently packaged it using electron-builder.

However upon running the packager, the builder created two executables titled:

```
<appName><versionNo>.exe
<appName>Setup<versionNo>.exe
```

Additional a Windows Installer Package was created titled:

```
<appName><versionNo>ia32.msi
```

Finally another executeable is located within a subdirectory included in the builder's newly created directory:

```
win-ia32-unpacked/<appName>.exe
```

Is there an order to which I should be running these, and should all be included if I was to move the packaged app to another machine?

Comment: you can just use your setup.exe to distribute.

Comment: If your pack configure is correct, then everything will be installed correctly.

Comment: I do appear to be missing some features when the file is transfered as outlined in this posting

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61806902/how-to-distribute-a-built-executable-constructed-using-electron-builder

Do you think this could be a packaging error?

Comment: Found the issue,

It involved my usage of a two package.json structure
Both dependencies and devDependencies were located in the root/package.json, where dependencies needed to be moved to the app/package.json file